# Swift framework and Cocoapods - integrate static libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, cocoa-touch

I created a cocoa touch framework with Swift as the preferred language.

On this framework I need to import static libraries, so I created a podfile and imported the pod using `use_frameworks!`

I created a bridging header and also added the pods source as header search path since it couldn't find the pod's header.

The framework compiles fine and I have no issues.

So I created a pod spec for the framework and created a sample app in swift. I had the framework as development pod in my podfile. Now I get

`Include of non-modular header inside framework module` in my bridging header import of the static library public header.

I understand since it's a static library we cannot build the touch framework, but what would be the work around to have a touch framework with static libraries in them written in Swift.

PS I have set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to `Yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my original question. It seems to be an issue with cocoapods(0.36.2) for vendor libraries where there is no implementation file.

There is a hack to get this working and you can take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3701)